# Why don't the heptapods know English?

Tags: arrival

The heptapods should have a good working knowledge of English given that they're

> from 3000 years in the future and they came back to make humans stronger

Was there another reason for them not knowing/using English? Were they forcing humans to learn their language as a team building exercise?

Comment: Because humanity wouldn't have united if they'd just turned up and said "hi".

Comment: Also the heptapods aren't *from* the future. They *see* the future.

Comment: You have entirely missed the point of the movie if you don't understand why the heptapods want Humanity to learn their language.

Comment: @DJClayworth - Notably, the reason in the movie is different from the book. In the movie it's to strengthen us for the trials ahead, in the book it's to help us to help them break out of the cycle of fixed time.

Comment: How much Summerian do you know?

Comment: @Valorum IMO you still misunderstood the Chiang's story but question is about movie, whatever

Comment: @SJuan76: only the basics: please, thank you, excuse me, where is the station, my hovercraft is full of eels.

Answer (score 14):

It has already been said in the comments, but just to formalize the answer:

The reason they don't just speak English (or any other human language for that matter) is because they want *us* to learn *their* language, so that we gain the ability to perceive time as they do, and will therefore do what it necessary to help them 3000 years from now, to help them with their crisis.

(In fact we know that the Heptapods *do* know English - at least Costello does - because when Louise is talking to him after the bomb scene, she speaks English and he responds without waiting for a translation.)